# Is (*&a) a lvalue or a rvalue?

Tags: c, operators, rvalue, lvalue, unary-operator

First of all, I think it's a `rvalue`, but the following fact changed my mind.

I tried an expression as `&(*&a)` and it works fine, but the operator `&` can just work with a `lvalue`, so `(*&a)` is a `lvalue`, why?

Comment: `&` never yields an lvalue.  `*` always does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per C 2018 6.5.3.2 4 (discussing the `unary *` operator), the result of unary `*` is an lvalue:

> … If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object.…

This tells us that `*&a` is an lvalue. However, the expression asked about in the question is `(*&a)`, so we must consider the effect of the parentheses.

6.3.2.1 2 (discussing automatic conversions) seems to tell us that `(*&a)` is converted to the value in `*&a` and is not an lvalue:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called *lvalue conversion*.

However, 6.5.1 5 (discussing parenthesized expressions) contradicts this:

> A parenthesized expression is a primary expression. Its type and value are identical to those of the unparenthesized expression. It is an lvalue, a function designator, or a void expression if the unparenthesized expression is, respectively, an lvalue, a function designator, or a void expression.

This is a defect in the C standard; 6.5.1 5 and 6.3.2.1 2 contradict each other. It is left to us to understand that 6.5.1 5, which is specifically about parenthesized expressions, takes precedence over the more general 6.3.2.1 2, and this is how all C implementations behave.

Thus `(*&a)` is an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

This expression `&(&a)` is invalid and will not work.

According to the C Stnadard

> 1 The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function
>   designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, **or an lvalue**
>   that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared
>   with the register storage-class specifier.

and

> 3 The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the
>   operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’. If
>   the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator
>   nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
>   omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply
>   **and the result is not an lvalue.**

So the result of the expression `&a` is not an lvalue. So you may not apply the operator `&` to the expression like `&&a`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    &( &x );

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gcc 8.3 issues an error

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:7:2: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
  &( &x );
  ^
```

This expression `*&a` is valid and the result is an lvalue.

> 4 The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; **if it points to an
>   object, the result is an lvalue designating the object**. If the
>   operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If
>   an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
>   unary * operator is undefined.

Bear in mind that parentheses do not influence on whether the enclosed expression is an lvalue or not.

Comment: But in both gcc & clang the expression works fine, why?

Comment: @Claim Yang No, it does not work. The compiler issues an error.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that something in my question goes wrong. My expression is "&(*&a)", and the standard 4 in your post answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: The expression asked about in the question is `(*&a)`, not `*&a`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The parentheses do not influence on whether the expression is an lvalue or not.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Sure, but that is not a given. The compiler has to be programmed to behave that way, and the behavior is specified by the C standard. You cannot just take it as automatically true—it is not automatically true, anymore than it is automatically true that `*` produces an lvalue or `+` performs addition. These things were all created, and the reasons they behave the way they do have to be explained.